# Should I trust download.oracle.com if my certificate does not match?

Tags: firefox, java, certificate, jdk

I've been getting this every time I try to download a JDK 8 update to my MacBook.

1. First, I go here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
2. I click the download location and go here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
3. I accept the license agreement and click **jdk-8u25-macosx-x64.dmg**, which sends me here: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-macosx-x64.dmg

As you can tell, I already started downloading the .dmg, but I have not installed it yet. I'm running on Firefox 34.0.

[image: This Connection is Untrusted download.oracle.com]

Here is the certificate:

[image: Bad Oracle Certificate]

Comment: Give us info about the cert itself

Comment: Do you get the same problem when going here? https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp I do not need to download it (so i cant fully test) but at least the script parts are saying "javadl.sun.com" not this other location?

Comment: Added @Ramhound.

Comment: And @Psycogeek, I need the JDK, not the JRE. It downloads via HTTP so it does not have any of these cert issues at least. I'll post a step-by-step as to how I got to this download.

Comment: I can't confirm it until tonight.  It appears the certificate isn't configure for that particular use, so the warning in question, is safe to ignore.  I get a warning with IE11 but that might be for an entirely different reason.  Why are you using the https url instead of the http [url](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-macosx-x64.dmg)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was causing this... [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere). I knew I disabled it for a reason... Anyway, it found the rule "Oracle (Partial)", so as soon as I disabled the rule and clicked the download again, it worked fine.